# Start of transmission in 802.11 Physical layers

Tags: wifi

What are the factors affecting the start of transmission by the physical layer after receiving data from the MAC layer?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the implementation. Generally speaking, the MAC indicates the exact time were the transmission shall start. In practice the PHY needs a rx/tx turnaround duration before starting the transmission and this usually is taken into account by the MAC.

If this does not answer your question, then you need to be more specific.